# What's the difference between primitive and composite function in CNTK?

Tags: deep-learning, cntk

From what I've learned, `as_block` function is used to turn composite function to primitive function. But what's the difference between the two? In what condition do I need to use this function? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments of a composite function vs. primitive function are different. primitive function's arguments are the variables used as direct input, while composite function traces back to the beginning of graph.

For example, if you have code like:

`a = b * c
s = a + d`

If you inspect s.arguments, you'll find b, c and d. This is because the primitive function `Plus` is wrapped with as_composite. But you can inspect s.owner.arguments, and it'll show a and d, which are the direct inputs to Plus.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer! But I still don't know what does the `block_arguments_map` parameter in `as_block` mean. Can you give an example for that?

Comment: You can consider block function a template in C++. as_block creates the template as well as instantiates it, so it needs a map from the invoking instance's input to the template's input.